# Ruby Nested Array to Javascript

Tags: arrays, nested

Guys, it's my first question, :). I'm trying to do as the title says. Here is my code:

in Ruby :

```
<% _points = Array.new %>

<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <% _points.push([user.latitude, user.longitude]) %>
<% end %>
```

I wanna use _points in a javascript fonction so i do it:

```
<script>
    var points = new Array();
    points = <%=raw _points%>;

    for (x in points) {
      setInterval(function () {
        var b = new R.BezierAnim([points[x], citylatlon], {}, function () {

        .......................

      }, 4000);
    }
</script>
```

finally, the funtction just can worked for le last array in ruby, help! Thx Guys.

Answer (score 0):

i found the way!

`var points = <%=_points.to_json%> ;`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            points.forEach(function (x, index, arr) {
                        animation_voyage(x);
                    }
            )
        }
);
```